# pvs vgs do not show existing drive group from multipath

Tags: raid, mount, multipath, disk-volume

I connected a raid system via multipath. `multipath -ll` show correctly the subdrives and the mapper is present under `/dev/mapper`.

However I cannot see any physical or volume group using `pvs`, `pvscan` `vgs` `vgscan` which I would like to import using `vgimport`.

I could use `pvcreate` but this would erase the current data on the raid.